# How to set value time in jSpinner from jTable

Tags: java, swing

```
  Date date = new Date();
  SpinnerDateModel sm  = new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  jSpinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner(sm);
  JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(jSpinner1, "h:mm:a");
  jSpinner1.setEditor(de);

  jSpinner1.setValue(jDelivery.getModel().getValueAt(row, 7)); // this one is my prblem
```

My problem is, i dont know how to setvalue in spinner using time

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "time" in the last sentence? A `java.time.LocalTime` instance? The time part in a `java.util.GregorianCalendar`? The time part in a `java.util.Date`? Your question does not make clear what the type of the value is your are setting in the JSpinner. The fact that this value is coming from a JTable cell is really irrelevant here. Can you clarify first what the type of the value is in the JTable cell?

Comment: Also, better describe what the actual problem is you are experiencing with the code you have. Do you get an exception (if so, include it in your question)? Do you get an invalid time displayed? Please [edit] your question and further clarify.